# How to run a main method from Spark (in Databricks)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, databricks

I created a simple Scala code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object app2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    println(s"This is a simple scala code v2 - it is running a Spark code.")
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

Then compiled with SBT which created JAR file.

Then added that JAR to Spark notebook with:

```
sc.addJar("some/path")
```

How do I run (invoke) this main method (app2) inside Databricks notebook in order to see the output of 'println' command?

Comment: [followed this?](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/01%20Databricks%20Overview/06%20Jobs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 'Ronak'. Seems this is a winning combination of a scala code:

```
/* app4.scala */ 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object app4 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val goodSparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    println(s"This is a simple scala code v4 - it is running a Spark code.")
  }
}
```

Comment: how does this answer the OP's question?